# cakephp auth->loginRedirect for admin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, admin

I'm fairly new to cakePHP and have read all the tutorials on the cake site. I'm building a small sample app using cake 2.1 and have hit a problem. Basically, I want admin users redirected to a different page on login than what a normal user gets redirected to. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I'm struggling!

I have Admin routing enabled and am using the auth component (and the ACL component though that's not affecting my issue). I have 2 logins one for admin - admin_login() and a login for normal users  - login() - the normal non admin login works fine.

In my AppController.php I have this:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

public function beforeFilter() {
    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->allow('display'); // Allows access to the homepage of the app
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');
}
```

}

So as you can see the default is for users to be redirected on login to the posts controllers add() function, which works fine. However, how can I set a different login redirect for my admin_login() function?

I've read a number of posts on here but most relate to older versions of cake and not cake 2.

If it helps, this is my admin_login function in the UsersController.php

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('logout');
}

public function admin_login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
                //$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

                // This doesnt work! Grrrrrr
                //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'admin_index'));

                // This nearly works...
                if($this->Auth->user())$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'admin_index'));
            }            
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }
    }
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have role -> "admin, user" in your database, put in your AppController - beforeFilter():

```
if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin'){
     $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller1', 'action' => 'action1');
}else{
     $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller2', 'action' => 'action2');
}
```

If you want to know what is in your $this->Auth->user() just put:

```
debug($this->Auth->user());
```

Comment: Thanks, I have something similar (user_group) so I've used that - however I've done it within the admin login function, would it be better to do it in the beforeFilter as you suggest?

Should it go in the AppController before filter or the UsersController beforeFilter? - Thanks for your help

Comment: Put it in AppController beforeFilter() and in UsersController beforeFilter() put:

**public function beforeFilter(){
parent::beforeFilter();
//other code
}**

Comment: If you didn't make it, you can add me on MSN, Skype or Facebook and I'll look at your code. :)

Comment: Ok, I've followed your instructions without luck. It doesnt redirect it just leaves you on the login page but displayes the logined flash msg.

Unfortunately I dont have access to IM or FB at work :(

I'm beginning to thik the issues is tied to admin routing. As onceI'm logged in if I manually nagivate to /admin/ it redirects me to the auth->loginRedirect in your code...

Comment: I'm going to open a new questions as I'm sure this is related to admin routing. As I have admin routing turned on in core.php and have attached a route to the admin_index() function in my pages controller yet when I visit admin it doesnt work. I'll mark this as correct as I think the issue lies elsewhere and your answer really helped.

Comment: This solution is incorrect, $this->Auth->user is not set at the point that beforefilter is called and so in the case of the above example the if part would never be true and therefore the else part would always be 'true'. The code above should be in the 'login' method in UsersController

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
if($this->request->params['admin']) {
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true);
}
else {
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add');
}
```

Replace your loginRedirect setting in beforeFilter() with these lines

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggestion however when I log in as admin it just leaves me on the login page. I have this within the admin_login() function:

public function admin_login() {
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {
         if ($this->Auth->login()) {
          if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
           $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
           $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());