# cakePHP- setting loginRedirect from beforeFilter for admin role

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am facing this weird problem. I am trying to change the default loginRedirect of the admin role from that of normal user.

U have the auth key in the AppController's component variable set up as follows :

```
'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(  
                'controller' => 'donors',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
    )
```

Now in the beforeFilter callback I have this set up:

```
if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin'){
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
            'controller'=>'users',
            'action'=>'admin_index',
            'prefix'=>'admin',
            'admin'=>true
        );
}
```

However, this does not work and the if condition is never met. I am expecting this to run when the user logs in. If I add an `else` condition and repeat the same code shown above, it  works and the admin is redirect to the desired page.

Can anyone instruct how I am able to do this correctly ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is not logged in, `$this->Auth->user()` will return null. beforeFilter() will run before any action is run, so your login() action has still not been called.

Do the redirecting after `$this->Auth->login()` has been called and is successful. E.g. in your `UsersController::login()` action (or whichever action you use to login):

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin') {
        $this->redirect(array(
            'controller'=>'users',
            'action'=>'admin_index',
            'prefix'=>'admin',
            'admin'=>true
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code inside the beforeRender(hoping it works) with the same logical steps you took! I will try what you are suggesting, and mark this as answer if it works. Is it wise to put this code within the login though? Thanks a million

Comment: Happy to help. In my opinion, your app's login() action is a logical place to redirect admin users upon successful login. Especially when you have a single login form for users with different roles, which would generally be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$this->Auth->loginRedirect` use `$this->redirect(
        array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_index');`

Its less complicated

Comment: Hi igor, thanks for your reply! And whilst I agree with you, It is not the problem, since the problem is that the `$this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin'` is resulting to false somehow and causing the code block to not execute.. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626741/cakephp-auth-loginredirect-for-admin) is from where I got the condition code