# Different login redirects for different user types

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

After login, I want to redirect user type admin to one page, and user type member to a another page. How?

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to explain what you have at present, otherwise it can generate a lot of additional comments for clarification. As a rule, one-sentence questions here aren't a great fit, since there's no evidence of prior research.

Comment: Sure, but I didn't think any more clarification was needed. It was a simple question and I got the right answer right away.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734175/cakephp-setting-loginredirect-from-beforefilter-for-admin-role/21734618#21734618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login function would be something like

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $userType = $this->Auth->user('type');
            if ($userType == 'admin') {
               $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
            } else {
               $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I don't have to use the `loginRedirect` parameter, I can do it manually. Thanks!