# On login redirect two different user to two different controller pages on the basis of their role

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I am using cakephp 2x. I am having trouble redirecting login user on the basis of their role.I am using two role admin and collegesupervisor. I want if admin login he redirects to user controller, index page and if collegesupervisor login  he redirects to collegeprofiles controller , addinfo page.Is it possible to redirects different user on the basis of their role without using cakephp Acl component??Thanks in Advance.. Here is my Appcontroller and usercontroller code....

```
 //AppController
<?php
/**
  * Application level Controller
 *
 * This file is application-wide controller file. You can put all
 * application-wide controller-related methods here.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc.      (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT    License
 */

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

 /**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package             app.Controller
 * @link                http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-   app-controller
 */
 class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array(
'Session',
'Auth' => array(
     'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
    'authError' => 'You do not have the authority to view this page.',
    'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password entered, please try     again.',
      'authorize' => array('Controller'),

  ));

public function isAuthorized($user) {
 // Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role

  return true;
```

}

```
// only allow the login controllers only
 public function beforeFilter() {
 parent::beforeFilter();
 $this->layout = 'bootstrap';
 $this->Auth->allow("login","logout");
 $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
 $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());



$wr=$this->webroot;

//$this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());
$user1 = $this->Session->read("Auth.User");
  $user=$user1['username'];
   //pr($user);
 $this->set(compact('user','wr'));

 $this->set('admin', $this->_isAdmin());


}


     function _isAdmin()
  {
  $admin = FALSE;
if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin')
 {
$admin = TRUE;
 }
 return $admin;
 }
}

 //User Controller

 <?php
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
 /**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property User $User
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
 class UsersController extends AppController {

 /**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
 public $components = array('Paginator');

 /**
 * index method
  *
 * @return void
 */ public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login','logout'); 



}

public function isAuthorized($user)
 {
    if($user['role']== 'admin')
        return true;
    if(in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete', 'add')))
    {
        if($user['id'] != $this->request->params['pass'][0])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

 public function login() {

    //if already logged-in, redirect
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'football_results','action' =>  'index2 '));      
    }

    // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth- >user('username')));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
         }
    } 
}
  public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

 public function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}


/**
* add method
*
* @return void
*/
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'),    'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved.    Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like following in `AppController - beforeFilter():`

`if($this->Auth->user('role') == 'admin'){
     $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller1', 'action' => 'action1');
}else{
     $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller2', 'action' => 'action2');
}`

[See accepted answer of related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626741/cakephp-auth-loginredirect-for-admin)

Answer (score 0):

this problem is a perfect fit for cakephp's event system. inside your users controller login action, dispatch an event e.g 'afterLogin' and put your post login logic there

```
public function login() {
      if($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        $event= new CakeEvent('Controller.users.afterLogin',$this, $this->Auth->user());
     $manager = $this-getEventManager();
     $manager->dispatch($event);
     }
    }

/* @Event afterLogin
*/
 public function afterLogin($user) {
       //check roles against acl and redirect
        if($user('role') == 'admin'){
 $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller1', 'action' => 'admin');
        }else{
          $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'controller2','action' => 'supervisor');
         }
         }
```